# Task updating properties on Main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to update property on my main Thread, which is bind to ProgressBar. In viewmodel I have the bellow code, which is not working.

```
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    DoLongRunningWork();

}).ContinueWith(_=>
{   

    ApplicationStatus = "Task finished!";

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());


DoLongRunningWork()
{
    // Alot of stuff

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ProgressBarValue += progressTick;
    }).Start(uiScheduler);
}
```

Comment: Explain `not working`

Comment: The ProgressBarValue += progressTick; is not updated

Comment: Which version of framework? and what are the type of variables `ProgressBarValue` and `progressTick`?

Comment: .NET 4 , both are double type.... The code without threading is working fine, hoewever In the above Task the ProgressBarValue is not updated causing ProgressBar to not show any progress

Comment: Did you tried to debug the program?

Comment: how you are binding on  ProgressBarValue

Comment: You are updating the `ProgressBarValue` in a task which is in another task. It should be updated by the UI thread. Or you should use `SomeControl.Invoke` BTW: the outer task completes immediately since it only creates another task(doing the actual work) and then finishes

Comment: Hmm.. I do specify the uiScheduler which is main Thread? Since I am using MVVM and I think I shoudnt/can't use SomeControl.Invoke . This is why I am asking of updating a property which is found in Main thread

Comment: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => ProgressBarValue += progressTick));` as in this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1644254/2609288

Comment: You should be getting an exception that explains what the issue is. (Hint: you can't start  `Task` twice.)

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ProgressBarValue += progressTick)); did the job

Answer (score 4):

If the property `ProgressBarValue` is bound to a WPF element, then the only thread that can update the `ProgressBar` is the very thread that created it.

So, my assumption is that the class that contains `ProgressBarValue` also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This means that you have some logic that raises the event `PropertyChanged`.

I would create a method that raises the event, and always does so using the `Dispatcher`.  (The `Dispatcher` allows you to call functions on the thread that created your WPF controls.)

```
private void raisePropertyChanged(string name)
{
  Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>
  {
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  });
}
```

This will always update the `ProgressBar` on the proper thread.

Comment: This property as well as whole class already implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Then all you need to do is use the `Dispatcher` whenever you raise the `PropertyChanged` event.