# C#: Can I just update a progress bar from a DLL by calling an Action Delegate?

Tags: c#, dll, progress-bar

I have already spent one whole week researching on this but things are not working for me.

I have a `WPF` UI with a progress bar. My business logic is in a seperate DLL. I want to update the progress bar from the DLL. I have a `SetProgress(int)` method on the UI side. I am passing this method as a Action delegate to the DLL and calling it from within the DLL to update progress. But I notice that the progress bar is not updating at the real time. Instead, after all the processing is done the progress bar suddenly reaches 100% which is not the desirable behaviour.

I also tried BackGroundWorker but I was unable to get a real time progress bar update with that either. Here is my approach on the BackGroundWorker way:

**UI Code:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public BackgroundWorker bw;
    public MainWindow()
    {            
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        ProgressChangedEventHandler(OnProgressChanged);                 
    }

    public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {            
        SetProgress(args.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    public void SetProgress(int progress)
    {      
        progressBar.Text = percent.ToString();
    }

    public void btn_click()
    {
         DoSomething(bw);
    }
}
```

**DLL Code:**

```
     Public void DoSomething(BackgroundWorker bw)
     {
           bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
           bw.RunWorkerAsync();
     }


     public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
          BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          { 
                worker.ReportProgress(i + 1);
          }
     }
```

I do not know where I am going wrong because this code too doesnt update the progress bar at real time.

Comment: This may be a solution : http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx

Comment: I also found the following comment somewhere _If you're using Windows 7 (don't know about Vista), I have to change the DispatcherPriority to Input (or lower) before it'll work._

Answer (score 0):

Where are you 'hooking up' the event `ProgressChanged` to your `OnProgressChanged` method on the BackgroundWorker? Extend your `MainWindow` constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{            
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    // this....
    bw.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged; 
}
```

---

Don't forget, if you want to update a UI element from another thread in WPF, you **must** invoke it on the `Dispatcher`  (thread).

example:

```
public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{            
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => SetProgress(args.ProgressPercentage) );
}

public void SetProgress(int progress)
{      
    progressBar.Text = percent.ToString();
}
```

This way the UI element is updated on the right thread.

Here's some more information about updating UI controls on other threads: [Change WPF controls from a non-main thread using Dispatcher.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I did hook up the ProgressChanged Method in my constructor, like this bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(OnProgressChanged);

Comment: I added the Dispatcher.Invoke in the OnProgressChanged() method, yet the behaviour is the same, the progress bar updates only after all the calculations are over and suddenly dashes to 100%.

Comment: within your `bw_DoWork`, there isn't much to do, or anything time consuming... does it go too fast?

Comment: I have tried adding a lot of work but the result is the same. I do not know why such a trivial task is not getting achieved :-(