# How can i set visible to true value in c# thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm beginner in c#,and i write this code for start the new thread:

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
workerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
workerThread.Start();
```

in the up thread process some thing and show into the chart,every thing is okay,but when run and finish `DoWork` method,chart control visible set to false automatically!,my `DoWork` method is:

```
public void DoWork()
{
     //.....some process and show into the process result into the chart
     chart1.Visible = true;//this code not run
}
```

how can solve that?

Comment: What project is this? Windows Form, WPF, Asp.Net ?   Please provide more code here. Where is you "code for start the new thread" located ?

Comment: Windows form,excuse me for forget that

Comment: is `chart1` a UI element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have access to UI elements from a different thread.

For Winforms:
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

For WPF:
[Change WPF controls from a non-main thread using Dispatcher.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread)

```
chart1.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>chart1.Visible = true);
```

Comment: If he **were** trying to access UI element from another thread, he should have got an exception thrown. I don't think he mentioned that...

Comment: Indeed, but for all you know he could've got an exception which was handled silently.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dowork method signature to accept object as parameter and pass Synchronization context to it:

```
    void DoWork(object o)
    {           
        SynchronizationContext cont = o as SynchronizationContext;

        // your logic gere
        cont.Post(delegate
        {
            // all your UI updates here 
        }, null);
    }

   Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
   workerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
   workerThread.Start(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```