# Get access to object in the different thread from console app c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a console app, where I want to show wpf window:

```
ths = new ThreadStart(() =>
  {
     window = new wpf_lib.Container();
     System.Windows.Application app = new Application();
     app.Run(window);
  });
 th = new Thread(ths);
 th.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 th.Start();
```

But, how I can get access for wpf window methods and properties from any method in the console app?

Answer (score 0):

You've two options, first and in your case easiest:

Use the [System.Windows.Application.MainWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get access to the Window's properties and methods.

Second: Add a property/method to the `Container` class that returns the `Window` object you want. This may or may not be possible, mostly depending on wether you've access to the source code of that class.

If you are encountering exceptions regarding thread access, use the `Dispatcher` of the appropriate WPF object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread) for details.