# How to bind a combo box to a collection asynchronously where the objects gets updated WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, binding

I have created a WPF binding it was working fine but then I realised I needed a refresh button show when I call the SetUpData function I am getting this error:

Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

C#:

```
public async void GetShows(string serviceDocUri)
{

    await Task.Run(() => _Shows = new ObservableCollection<Show>());

    await Task.Run(() => GetAllShowsWithPath("", directoryShowDoc)); //Error shows on this line
}
```

More C#:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = Workspace.This;

    //Awaits the list of shows
    SetUpData();
}
```

More C#:

```
private async void SetUpData()
{
    await Task.Run(() => _VizManager.GetShows(_TrioLocalHost));

    //This is binded to my WPF combobox
    Workspace.This.TrioShow = _VManager._Shows;

}
```

More C#:

```
private async Task GetAllShowsWithPath(string directoryPath, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    string siteRoot = "http://";
    foreach (XmlNode showNode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term='show']/atom:title", nameSpaceManager_))
    {
        _Shows.Add(new Show { Title = "showTitle", ShowLink = "showLink", FullPath = "fullPath" });
    }

    foreach (XmlNode dirNode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term='directory' and not(atom:category/@term='show')]/atom:title", nameSpaceManager_))
    {
        string dir = dirNode.InnerText;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
        string directoryPath1 = directoryPath + "/" + dir;
        string xml = "";
        string page = siteRoot + "/directory/shows" + directoryPath1 + "/";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
        {
            response.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/atomsvc+xml");
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    xml = data;
                }
            }
        }
        xmlDoc1.LoadXml(xml);
        await this.GetAllShowsWithPath(directoryPath1, xmlDoc1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't your methods return any values? What are they doing? GetAllShowsWithPath should certainly return all "shows with path".

Comment: Instead of returning the shows I add them directly to my list within "shows with path" function.

Comment: Well, then you should rename the methods. This code should never pass a code review :). Please show what the methods do exactly if you want someone to be able to point what else you are doing wrong.

Comment: What is the type of _Show?

Comment: My apologies I will edit the post so I have the full structure. and the _Shows is ObservableColection<Show>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a mess, to be honest. You don't call a method Get* if it doesn't return something, to begin with. And why are you creating and awaiting several tasks inside other tasks?

Anyway, the `ObservableCollection<Show>` should (must) be created on the UI thread. Create it the first thing you do in the constructor of the window or view model or wherever it's defined:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Shows = new ObservableCollection<Show>();
    this.DataContext = Workspace.This;

    //Awaits the list of shows
    SetUpData();
}
```

Your `GetAllShowsWithPath` method should then *return* an `IEnumerable<Show>` that you populate the data-bound `ObservableCollection` with back on the UI thread. You could change the return type of the method to `Task<List<Show>>` and return a list of objects instead of trying to access the `ObservableCollection` from within the method.

The other option would be to use the [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx) method to enable the collection to be accessed across multiple threads:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Shows = new ObservableCollection<Show>();
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_Shows, _lock);

    this.DataContext = Workspace.This;

    //Awaits the list of shows
    SetUpData();
}
```

You must still create the collection and call this method on the UI thread though.

Comment: Thanks, Also for the feedback on the coding standards. Have you got any recommendation for good coding standards or does that come with time?  I am always looking to move forward and learn new things.

Comment: You could refer to the C# programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions. Thanks for the edits by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are trying to access an UI element from another thread probably here:

```
//..Function body
//Recurring function
```

> UI element created on a thread is accessible only to that thread, and
>   is not available to other threads

Take a look at [Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/change-wpf-controls-from-a-non-main-thread-using-dispatcher-invoke)

[Edit]:

```
public async Task GetShows(string serviceDocUri)
{
    _Shows = new ObservableCollection<Show>();
    await Task.Run(
        () =>
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new Action(() => GetAllShowsWithPath("", directoryShowDoc))));
} 


private async Task SetUpData()
{
    await _VizManager.GetShows(_TrioLocalHost);

    //This is binded to my WPF combobox
    Workspace.This.TrioShow = _VManager._Shows;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that you are creating from another thread than the UI thread. See the edit