# Indeterminate progress bar not animating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is the code that instantiate a window with an indeterminate progress bar, this code is called in a viewmdodel of some view :

```
Views.InstallingWindow installing = new Views.InstallingWindow();
installing.Show();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(timeConsumingMethod, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
installing.Close();
```

And here is the xaml of the window

```
<Window x:Class="Blabla.Views.InstallingWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PatcherClient.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="InstallingWindow" Height="150" Width="300"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ProgressBar Width="200" Height="20" Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal" IsIndeterminate="True" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="StatusText" Margin="10" Height="50" Foreground="Black" Text="Installing ..."/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

On my computer, the progress bar does not animate. How to fix it ?

Comment: You can't execute timeConsumingMethod on the UI thread if you want it to be able to animate the ProgressBar.

Comment: Running long time consuming methods is not what the dispatcher is for, possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/change-wpf-controls-from-a-non-main-thread-using-dispatcher-invoke

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will execute `timeConsumingMethod` on the dispatcher thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(timeConsumingMethod, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

And the dispatcher cannot both execute your method and animate the `ProgressBar` simultaneously.

You want to execute `timeConsumingMethod` on a *background* thread. The easiest way to do this is to start a new `Task` and then close the window once the task has completed:

```
Views.InstallingWindow installing = new Views.InstallingWindow();
installing.Show();
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    timeConsumingMethod();
}).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    installing.Close();
}, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.None,
```

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Note that for this to work, you cannot access any `UIElement` in your `timeConsumingMethod()` method. A `UIElement` may only be accessed on the UI thread on which it was originally created.

Comment: thanks for this fast answer ! Because I use .Net 3.5 i worked out a solution using method.BeginInvoke(), and in the callback I use the Dispatcher to close the window. Actually, I had not noticed that the Dispatcher is for the UI objects, which is what everybody pointed out...

Answer (score 4):

`Dispatcher.Invoke` executes your `timeConsumingMethod` delegate on the UI thread so it will be blocked.

Try this instead in an `async` method:

```
installing.Show();
await Task.Run(() => timeConsumingMethod());
installing.Close();
```

If your `timeConsumingMethod` accesses any UI component (eg. sets control properties), then you should wrap these accesses into `Dispatcher.Invoke` only.