# How to add "Invoke" method to my project?

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget, invoke

I can't find the right NuGet packet to install the invoke method.
I have a wpf GUI and I have a separate thread that needs to update items in a listBox. I need the "Invoke" method in order to change the items in the listBox.

```
    public void displayPlayers(string players)
    {
        //spliting all the names.
        string[] names = players.Split(", ".ToCharArray());

        //Displaying the names.
        foreach (string name in names)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => playersListBox.Items.Add(name)));
    }
```

Comment: The `.Invoke` method is part of Winforms. You don't need to install it. And why have you said a "wpf GUI"?

Comment: It should be `playersListBox.Invoke(new Action(() => playersListBox.Items.Add(name)));`

Comment: @Enigmativity, Because of my lack of knowledge in this field... I'm really new to c# and wpf so my terminology is lacking.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria, It still gives me an error:
Error CS1061 'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no accessible extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Trivia_client C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Trivia_client\Trivia_client\WaitingRoom.xaml.cs 75 Active

Comment: @AnthonNaivelt I thought it was Winforms because of `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria oh, I see. No, I'm using wpf. I need a way to change the items displayed in the listBox.

Comment: @AnthonNaivelt take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/change-wpf-controls-from-a-non-main-thread-using-dispatcher-invoke).

Comment: @AnthonNaivelt - Can you please edit your question to remove references to Winforms and make it clear you mean WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method. It is accessible via `Application` class [(see more)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.current?view=netframework-4.8) or on the control itself. For more info see: [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you sir. I found it after I realized I was looking at WinForms forums.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
{
    playersListBox.Items.Add(name);
}));
```

Or without await:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
{
    playersListBox.Items.Add(name);
})).Wait();
```