# C# use multithread to write to richtextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a C# script to do a ping test on a network. I have it *mostly* working, except the part to write to richtextbox. I need to write results as the ping test is happening. I know it needs multithreading, but I have spent the past week trying to figure it out, and cannot. Here is the code I have, minus the unnecessary parts. The part I am having trouble with is the RunPingTest function. I will also include my sample xml for the IP addresses. All the buttons and other functions otherwise work as intended.

```
using System.Diagnostics;          
using System.Windows;              
using System.Xml.Linq;             
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetTestingTool
{
   public partial class NetTest : Window
   {
      static string dataFolder = "D:";
      static readonly string configPath = dataFolder + "\\ConfigFiles";
      
      //get HostIPAddresses.xml
      XElement GroupNames = XElement.Load(configPath + "\\HostIPAddresses.xml");
      bool testIsRunning = false;
      //Start the initial GUI

      public NetTest()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         //populate the dropdown
         foreach (var groupElement in GroupNames.Elements("Group"))
         {
            if (groupElement.Attribute("name").Value != null)
            {
               dropDown.Items.Add(groupElement.Attribute("name").Value);
            }
         }
      }

      //********** Button Actions **********
      //run the network test
      public void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         //clear richtextbox first
         resultsBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
         //first, make sure the user has selected a group
         if (dropDown.SelectedItem != null)
         {
            string HostSelection = (string)dropDown.SelectedItem;
            //create a list of IP addresses based on group chosen
            List<string> pingList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var groupElement in GroupNames.Elements("Group"))
            {
               //resultsBox.AppendText(groupElement.Attribute("name").Value);
               if (groupElement.Attribute("name").Value == HostSelection)
               {
                  // resultsBox.AppendText(groupElement);
                  foreach (var hostSystem in groupElement.Elements("HostSystem"))
                  {
                     if (hostSystem.Attribute("IPAddress").Value != null)
                     {
                        pingList.Add(hostSystem.Attribute("IPAddress").Value);
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            
            /*Should this be outside BtnStart_Click?
            currently cannot because it uses pingList*/
            void RunPingTest(object? obj)
            {
               //do the ping test
               resultsBox.AppendText("Doing the ping test \r"); //Just kidding, it isn't
               foreach (var pingElement in pingList)
               {
                  //this needs to be able to write to resultsBox as the ping happens (richtextbox)
                   Ping myPing = new Ping();
                   resultsBox.AppendText("Pinging " + pingElement + ". . . ");
                   PingReply reply = myPing.Send(pingElement, 2000); //ip and timeout
                   string results = reply.Status.ToString();
                   resultsBox.AppendText(results + "\r");
               }
               resultsBox.AppendText("\r\n Finished ping testing");
            }
         }
      } 
        //other buttons here
   }
}
```

xml for IPAddresses:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Systems>
   <Group name="Group1">
      <HostSystem name="System1" IPAddress="1.1.1.1"> </HostSystem> 
      <HostSystem name="System2" IPAddress="2.2.2.2"> </HostSystem>
      <HostSystem name="System3" IPAddress="3.3.3.3"> </HostSystem>  
   </Group>
   <Group name="Group2">
      <HostSystem name="System4" IPAddress="4.4.4.4"> </HostSystem>
      <HostSystem name="System5" IPAddress="5.5.5.5"> </HostSystem>
      <HostSystem name="System6" IPAddress="6.6.6.6"> </HostSystem>  
   </Group>
```

Comment: Or prefer async/await, mabe in conjunction with Progress<T>

Comment: `RunPingTest` isn't actually called in the example you posted from what I can tell.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/change-wpf-controls-from-a-non-main-thread-using-dispatcher-invoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the code you posted you never call the method `RunPingTest` which is probably why your `RichTextBox` never gets updated.

However, if you want to do this asynchronously, the `Ping` `class` contains a method called [`SendPingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-networkinformation-ping-sendpingasync(system-string-system-int32)) with a number of overloads that returns a `Task<PingReply>` and allows you to just use `async/await`. No need to introduce any kind of `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker` or manually deal with the `Dispatcher`.

```
private async void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pingList = new List<string>
    {
       "1.1.1.1",
       "2.2.2.2",
       "3.3.3.3",
       "4.4.4.4"
    };

    resultsBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    resultsBox.AppendText("Doing the ping test\r");
    using (var ping = new Ping())
    {
        foreach (var ip in pingList)
        {
            resultsBox.AppendText($"Pinging {ip} . . . ");
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000);
            resultsBox.AppendText($"{reply.Status} \r");
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is to make your event handler `async void` and to `await` the calls to `SendPingAsync`. You might also want to consider disabling 'BtnStart' until the method completes, otherwise users will be able to click on it while a ping test is still running.

Comment: This one worked beautifully and does just what I want, with no complicated multithread code. Thanks!! I am also in the process of disabling the run and exit buttons, and enabling cancel while it runs. Another step on my way to a complete script :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't access controls from threads other than your GUI thread.

A quick fix is to dispatch your `AppendText` to the main thread by saving the main `Dispatcher` object in your constructor and using it to invoke your append (using `BeginInvoke`) on the main thread.

Among other things you should probably work on improving are not instantiating multiple `Ping` objects and not using a rich text box at all, what you have are log entry lines which are much better modeled as an observable array of strings bound to an `ItemsControl`.

Edit: Also use `Path.Combine` to combine paths, your string concatenation is incredibly brittle.

Answer (score -1):

I have enough comments about your design and code, but to help you with your question here how to update resultsBox from a thread:

```
if (resultsBox.InvokeRequired)
{               
  this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
  {
     // you can do anything to resultBox here  (1)
  });
}
else
{
   // do it here (2)
}
```

To avoid duplicate code at 1 and 2 create a new method UpdateResultBox()  to put all your logic, your code will be:

```
if (resultsBox.InvokeRequired)
{               
  this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
  {
     UpdateResultsBox();
  });
}
else
{
     UpdateResultsBox();
}

private void UpdateResultsBox()
{
  // put your logic here
}
```